# Select max value from different column in a row in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, max, oracle-sqldeveloper

My table in oracle database is like this:

```
Rollno  |   mark1   |   Mark2   |   mark3
--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
101     |   10      |   20      |   30
102     |   22      |   44      |   08
103     |   55      |   11      |   14
--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

And I want output like

```
Rollno  |   MAX(Mark1,mark2,mark3)
--------+-------------------------+
101     |   30
102     |   44
103     |   55
--------+-------------------------+
```

Any query suggestion?

Comment: Which dbms? Some products have a GREATEST function. NULL possible?

Comment: Use the `greatest` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GREATEST` function

```
SELECT Rollno, GREATEST (mark1, Mark2, mark3) AS Maxv
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Sorry, saw Oracle first after asking.

Answer (score 1):

`ANSI SQL` compliant answer, written before Oracle was specified:

Use `CASE` to find largest column value:

```
select Rollno, case when mark1 > mark2 and mark1 > mark3 then mark1
                    when mark2 > mark3 then mark2
                    else mark3 end as max_value
from tablename
```

(`NULL`'s not considered here.)